# Python: modifying list of ints to list of strs using for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
def temperature(weather):
'''(list of ints) -> list of strs
Modify and return list, replacing each temp in list for weather condition. 
Hot being over 25 degrees, and cool being under.
'''
```

So, if I run temperature([24, 29, 11]), I want it to return ['cool', 'hot', 'cool'].

This is what I got. I think I'm creating a new list instead of modifying it though. How would I modify a list instead of making a new list using a for loop?

```
temp =[]
for degrees in weather:
    if degrees > 25:
        temp = temp + ['hot']
    else:
        temp = temp + ['cool']
return temp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While modifying the input list is usually a bad idea, if you really want to do that, use `enumerate` to get the indices and element access notation to change the list contents:

```
for index, degrees in enumerate(weather):
    if degrees > 25:
        weather[index] = 'hot'
    else:
        weather[index] = 'cold'
```

If you make a new list, don't say

```
temp = temp + [whatever]
```

That creates a copy of `temp` to append the new item, and can degrade performance to quadratic time. Instead, use

```
temp += [whatever]
```

or

```
temp.append(whatever)
```

both of which modify `temp`.

Comment: `enumerate()` is overkill. Just slice-assign.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: True, but the question said "instead of making a new list". Slice-assigning would most likely involve making a new list to slice-assign into the old one.

Comment: Just wondering, is there another way to modify the input list without using enumerate?

Comment: @user2489861: You could use `range(len(weather))` to just iterate over the indices, or you could do what Ignacio was saying and create a new list, then use `weather[:] = new_list` to replace the contents of the old list with the contents of the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Never mutate arguments passed to you.

```
temp = []
 ...
  temp.append('hot')
   ...
  temp.append('cool')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension with ternary expression:

```
>>> lis = [24, 29, 11]
>>> def func(lis):
...     return ['hot' if x > 25 else 'cool' for x in lis]
... 
>>> func(lis)
['cool', 'hot', 'cool']
```

Modifying the same list:

```
>>> lis = [24, 29, 11]
>>> id(lis)
3055229708L
>>> lis[:] = ['hot' if x > 25 else 'cool' for x in lis]
>>> id(lis)
3055229708L
```

Simple loop based solution:

```
>>> temp = []
for x in lis:
    if x > 25:
        temp.append('hot')
    else:    
        temp.append('cool')
>>> temp
['cool', 'hot', 'cool']
```